# Undefined index in PHP script

Tags: php, android

Undefined index: phone_no in **C:\wamp\www\gcm_server_php\check_user.php** on line **11**
 getting this error but php code working fine in browser and getting response code 200

Android Code

```
 package com.pushnotification;

 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class JsonArray extends Activity {

Button btnAsonArray;
JSONObject listOfNumbers = null;

String listNumber;
String browserString = "?phone_no=";
String url = CommonUtilities.LOCAL_CHECK_USER_URL;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.josn_array);

    btnAsonArray = (Button) findViewById(R.id.josnArray);
    btnAsonArray.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            readNumberAndNAme();

            // Log.e("", "In Onclick Methos :- " + jsonObject);
        }
    });
}

private void readNumberAndNAme() {
    try {
        Log.e("", "in Read Numbers And Name Method :- ");

        listNumber = "9465383066";
        HttpResponse re = HTTPPoster
                .doPost(url, browserString + listNumber);
        String temp = EntityUtils.toString(re.getEntity());

        Log.e("", "=======Task Comleted sucessfully ========" + temp);
        int j = 0;
        while (j != 5) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Length of Result :- " + temp.length(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            j++;
        }

        if (temp.compareTo("SUCCESS") == 0) {

            Log.e("", "Sending complete!");

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Another class of android

```
 package com.pushnotification;

 import java.io.IOException;

 import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader;
 import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

 import android.util.Log;

 public class HTTPPoster {

public static HttpResponse doPost(String url, String c)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

    Log.e("", "URL from Http Poster Class :- " + url
            + "Data to send server :- " + c);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    HttpEntity entity;
    StringEntity s = new StringEntity(c.toString());

    s.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
            "application/json"));
    entity = s;
    request.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response;
    response = httpclient.execute(request);

    Log.e("", "================Method Executed sucessfully================"
            + response);
    return response;
}

 }
```

PHP Code

```
 $phone_no = $_REQUEST["phone_no"];


include_once 'GCM.php';
include_once 'db_functions.php';
$gcm = new GCM();
$db = new db_functions();
$result = $db->isPhoneExisted($phone_no);
if($result>0)
{

    $message = array("product" => "abc");


    echo "true";
}
else 
{

    $message = array("product" => "abc");


    echo "false";
 }


?>
```

Comment: android HTTP request isn't sending any field named "phone_no". That's because you're sending a POST request as it was a GET request (POSTs don't use querystrings!) Try to fix that, maybe it'll resolve the issue

Comment: @STTLCU `$_REQUEST` handles both requests i.e. post or get

Comment: I know that, still, maybe the HTTPPost implementation in android discards the querystring? It'd be worth to check that.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `$phone_no` is not set or defined therefore you see this error

use [**isset**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
$phone_no = $_REQUEST["phone_no"];

if(isset($phone_no)){
include_once 'GCM.php';
include_once 'db_functions.php';
$gcm = new GCM();
$db = new db_functions();
$result = $db->isPhoneExisted($phone_no);
if($result>0)
{

    $message = array("product" => "abc");


    echo "true";
}
else 
{

    $message = array("product" => "abc");


    echo "false";
 }
}else{
echo "phone no. is empty";
}

?>
```

Comment: this is merely solving the symptoms, not the cause.

Comment: Read my else case enough to define what was missing

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `$phone_no` variable

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["phone_no"]))  { 
     $phone_no = $_REQUEST["phone_no"];
    }
```

Comment: this is merely solving the symptoms, not the cause.

Comment: I 
stick with the current condition

Comment: Undefined variable: phone_no in <b>C:\wamp\www\gcm_server_php\check_user.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
 getting this error means not getting phone number from android code so issue in android code can review my android code